# What is the output format for symbol size in output of nm utility

Tags: c, object, nm

I am using the following command

```
nm -B -l -r --size-sort --print-size binaryName| grep ' B '
```

Sample output:

```
00000000166140e0 0000000000aae608 B tax_dtl_buf
```

Here `00000000166140e0` is the size of the symbol `tax_dtl_buf`.

Can anyone explain how to interpret this size? I mean how to convert it to kilobyte.

Answer (score 7):

Actually **0000000000aae608** is the size. It's in hexadecimal notation. You can get it in decimal instead, with the flag "-t d". Just divide by 1024 to get kilobytes.